# Navigate through a "chain" in OrientDB

Tags: java, performance, orientdb

**Background:**

I am new in OrientDB, I will test it in Java for some days to see if it is the DB that I need.

**Context:**

Suppose you have something similar to a LinkedList, but made with vertex and (O) edges (-):

O - O - O - O - O - O - O - O

Each vertex has a field called "name" and an edge labeled "bestFriend".

**Question:**

I need to print the names of all of the vertex of the "chain". Is there any way or API method to navigate through the entire list in a fast way, with a complexity < O(n)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
select name from ( traverse out('bestFriend') from #10:44 )
```

Assuming #10:44 is the root vertex's id.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
How can I achieve the same from Java? Maybe using OTraverse object?

Comment: OTraverse traverse = orientGraph.traverse();
  for(OIdentifiable obj : traverse.field("in").field("out_bestFriend").target(new ORecordId("#10:44")).execute()){
   System.out.println(obj);
  }